# How to convert BBM bin  to DeviceId

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me

I convert bin from members to numbers and characters using this line

```
String bin=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(DeviceInfo.getDeviceId(),16))
```

Now how to convert bin again to DeviceId (only numbers)

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the reverse:

```
String rev=Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin));
```

for example, this code:

```
String bin=Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt("12345678",16));
String rev=Integer.toHexString(Integer.parseInt(bin));
System.out.println(bin);
System.out.println(rev);
```

outputs:

```
305419896
12345678
```

Comment: "toHexString" takes 1 int arg, and "Integer.parseInt" causes java.lang.NumberFormatException

Comment: The cirrect answer is: int intValue = Integer.parseInt(bin, 16);